# SQL Server 2008 Transactional Replication Between Databases That Have Table With Same Columns Name But Different Column Order

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactional-replication

I'm new with replication. My company is using Ms. Dynamics Navision 2009. Now I need to replicate all databases from the branches to a single database for reporting purpose.
This is the structure of the Databases

### SOURCE

```
DB Name     : [BRANCH ONE]
TABLE Name  : [Branch One$Table1]
COLUMN Name : C1, C2, C3, C4
PRIMARY KEY : C1
--------------------------------------
DB Name     : [BRANCH TWO]
TABLE Name  : [Branch Two$Table1]
COLUMN Name : C1, C2, C3, C4
PRIMARY KEY : C1
--------------------------------------
    . . .
--------------------------------------
DB Name     : [BRANCH XXX]
TABLE Name  : [Branch XXX$Table1]
COLUMN Name : C1, C2, C3, C4
PRIMARY KEY : C1
```

### DESTINATION

```
DB Name     : [REPORT DB]
TABLE Name  : [Company$Table1]
COLUMN Name : C1, C4, C2, C3
PRIMARY KEY : C1, C4
Note: Column C4 contain Branch ID. In Navision, column is sorted by Primary Key first.
```

When I try to setup these replication, the value of column C4 (REPORT DB) is always filled by the value of column C2 (BRANCH DB). I have try using custom store procedure for INSERT, but the result is always the same as previous.

I know how to setup a one-to-one transactional replication, but never had a successfull run with many-to-one setup. Please help me to setup this replication. I have googling for many-to-one replication example/tutorial but with no luck. Especially replication between tables with different column order.
Thank You..

Best Regards,

Arfan Septianto

Answer (score 0):

Could you drop the column C4 and Add it back to the table on Destination?

If not, you can modify the stored procedures for replication, naming MsIns*****, MsUpd*****, to reflect the inconsistent column order.

Comment: Yes, currently all I can do is alter all table to remove the primary key from C4, and restore the database from Nav. After restore, re-alter the tables to add the PK on C4. It's work, but not solve the problem. <br />Already try to modify those store procedure, but still C2 value got entered on the C4...